# No Scrollbar appearing for WrapGrid in Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, grid, grid-layout

I currently have a WrapGrid bound to an ObservableCollection of BitmapImages. What I wish is for these to be displayed, 4 items per row, extending downwards - and when the WrapGrid extends past the size of the users screen, allow the user to scroll downwards. Currently it is working - but no scrollbar appears and the user is unable to scroll downwards - so whenever it extends beyond the screen, the images are cut off and useless.

I believe something must be incorrect in how I have defined my grids ; but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I have done incorrectly after hours of searching.

Here is my code :

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Button x:Name="backButton"
            Click="GoBack"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}"
            Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />

       <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Image Gallery"
               Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" />
    </Grid>

   <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid Margin="120,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         ...
        <ItemsControl Name="listOfImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding}" Margin="10,10,10,0"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this stuff was set by default but may not be the case, so this may prove useful.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
              CanVerticallyScroll="True" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: CanVerticallyScroll is not supported by WrapGrid; the other attributes unfortunately make no difference. Thanks a lot for the response though :)

Comment: Well it is, according to the official docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid but apparently just for orientedvirtualizingpanel used with it. I'll come back to this shortly, surely we're over complicating things lol

Comment: Thank you for that! I think it's a case that the containing element needs to have a fixed size or something along these lines. I've seen people complain of scrollbars not appearing when the row size is set to "*", but all my experimenting has gotten me nowhere! :)